# Class member access through out of bounds access to array member

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-structures

I've seen a very experienced programmer do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef int BOOL;

BOOL is_max(int a) {
    return a&3;
}

class Foo
{
    public:
    inline Foo()    {}
    inline ~Foo()   {}

    int     min[3];
    int     max[3];
};

int main()
{   
    Foo foo = Foo();
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        foo.min[i] = i;
        foo.max[i] = i+3;
    }
    
    BOOL b = is_max(75); // b==3
    
    // Print out foo.max[1] (which is foo.min[4])
    cout << foo.min[1+b] << endl;
}
```

This is in a very computationally expensive part of the code. So I guess it's indeed faster than create branching with an if condition. Since both arrays (`max` and `min`) are of `int` type and contiguous in the class definition, this should always work.

Is there a reason one should avoid this approach? I know this is probably not the best for code readability and maintainability (e.g. if someone would add a third member in the class definition at the wrong place, i.e. between `min` and `max`). Probably a better approach would then tho have

```
int[6] extrema;
```

Other than that, would there be other downsides of that approach? Could this lead to premature termination/segmentation fault somehow?

Comment: Compiler can add arbitrary padding between members.

Comment: Beside of that, I think using `BOOL` as an integer type looks confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: You shouldn't do that because it is technically out of bound access and undefined behavior.

Comment: `int extrema[6]; int* min = &extrema[0]; int* max = &extrema[3];`?

Comment: *"Since both arrays (max and min) are of int type and contiguous in the class definition, this should always work."* This is not necessarily true, you cannot assume the arrays will be adjacent. But even if they are, it is still Undefined Behavior to try to derive a pointer to an element of `max` this way. For example the compiler is allowed to see `foo.min[1+b]` and assume that `b` is never more than 1 since it can be statically shown that it would be exceed its extend, then optimize accordingly.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow A nice example why `typedef int BOOL;` is a really bad idea... ;-)

Comment: Thank you all. It indeed seemed a very dangerous approach to me. Since the programmer is really quite skilled, I however wanted to have a confirmation that it can indeed be unsafe. Especially the BOOL typedef indeed confused me a lot in the beginning. I guess then that @MikeCAT's approach would be the best idea. This code is also pretty old and I guess the programmer wanted to save as much RAM as possible (and optimize cache access).

Comment: @David That is an approach that is sometimes seen in old C which did not have a boolean type. Older code bases may also have been written when Undefined Behavior may not have been seen as a big deal. Maybe because optimizations were narrower?

Comment: @David For the solution to work it has to be assumed that the two arrays are contiguous with each other, which implies no difference in memory layout with `int[6]`. So for this code to work it cannot save any memory and cannot help avoid cache misses, compared to using an actual single contiguous 6 element array.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Agreed, I was actually speaking of @MikeCAT's solution, where you would save two additional pointers (altough you could actually just save one for `max`).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux regarding your first comment, yes. The code is actually written in C++, but in a very C-like fashion. I guess your assumptions are correct.

Comment: Tell your colleague that tricks like this may have worked 10 or 15 years ago, but in this day and age of optimizing compilers, you can't rely on these hacks to either speed up the code or not have other adverse side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems, first of all, it is out of bounds access if `b` is larger then `1` and that is undefined behavior.

Another problem is, that the compiler only sees `foo.max[i] = i+3;` but has no indication in your code that `max` is used at any point after that loop. So from the perspective of the optimizer and because accessing `max` trough `min` is not valid, it could assume that `foo.max[i] = i+3;` in the loop is useless and could theoretically optimize it away.

And based on a short look at the compiled output of `gcc` with optimizations turned on this seems to be indeed the case.

So even if there wouldn't be any unknown padding involved and you could be sure about the memory layout it is still definitely something you must not do.